# Permission denied when using bash command in Python

Tags: python-3.x, bash, shell

I have a python script which looks something like this.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

process = Popen(['git log'], stdout=PIPE,stderr=PIPE)
stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
```

I am getting "Permission denied" when running this script.

Comment: Can you please verify that the problem occurs on the script as posted, and not just on your full version? Can you also include the command you used to run it, and the complete and unabbreviated error messages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no command whose name is `git log`; you want the command `git` with the argument `log`.

Tangentially, if you are on Python 3.5 or higher, you want to upgrade to `subprocess.run()`.

```
from subprocess import run, PIPE

result = run(['git', 'log'], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, text=True, check=True)
stdout = result.stdout
stderr = result.stderr
```

Comment: Why would it give a "permission denied" instead of a "No such file or directory" though?

Comment: I dunno; indeed, I get "no such file or directory". Maybe the OP is on some godforsaken "personal productivity" platform?