# Python 3.7.3 import subprocess throws an error

Tags: python-3.x

> Python 3.7.3 on AIX 7.1.0.0  import subprocess causes an error:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "main_iso_processing.py",
>   line 3, in 
>       import subprocess   File "", line 983, in _find_and_load   File "", line
>   963, in _find_and_load_unlocked   File "", line 906, in _find_spec   File "", line 1280, in find_spec   File
>   "", line 1249, in _get_spec
>   File "", line 1213, in
>   _path_importer_cache PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

I have removed or commented out everything except the print function and the import of subprocess.  If I comment out import subprocess, it works.  Also, I can import os or sys without getting the error.

```
#!/opt/bin/python3
import subprocess
print("starting...")
```

I would like to use subprocess to run some DataStage jobs.

Comment: Did my solution resolve your issue?  Did you find a different solution?  Just checking in.

Comment: @Fletchy1995, I appreciate the answer.  Soemthing I don't understand is that the import of os or sys does not throw an error.  What is different about the import of subprocess?

Comment: take a look at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39777345/subprocess-popen-oserror-errno-13-permission-denied-only-on-linux?rq=1 maybe this will help

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a permission denied error.  Perhaps the directory of your python environment is only accessible as a super user.  Try going to the directory of your python environment and changing permissions.

Linux, run this command:

```
$ sudo chown -R testuser:testuser /path/to/python
```

If you are unaware of your username type: `whoami` in the console and it will tell you.

Example for me:

```
$ whoami
>>> guest
$ sudo chown -R guest:guest /usr/bin/python3
```

Windows 10:
Follow instructions at this [link](https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/take-ownership-folder-windows-10-using-file-explorer)

Finally you may need to restart your computer for these changes to take effect.

Comment: Verose logging has an interesting line - Python 3.7.3 (default, May 10 2019, 07:51:10) [C] on aix6
I wonder if the problem is that subprocesss is calling something like pipes or ps or something else on AIX, to which it doe not have permission.

Comment: Possibly, I'll be honest in saying I'm unsure.

Comment: Someone else is having/had the same problem:    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52746387/permission-denied-when-using-bash-command-in-python/57790093#57790093                                                                                          I think it is an issue with permissions to the AIX pipe file(s), but am not sure.